# How to find the max subset sum when one int is removed from the subset?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I'm getting wrong answer when I run the program.It is a question from codechef contest .
Here is the link for question : https://www.codechef.com/TAW22021/problems/TAW221A1
Here is my code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   cin.tie(NULL);
   int t,p=0;
   vector<int> a;
   while(cin>>t)
   {
       a.push_back(t);
   }
   int var = *min_element(a.begin(),a.end());
   for(auto i=a.begin();i!=(a.end()-1);i++)
   {
       int val=*i;
       const auto begin = a.begin() + p;
       int q = p+1;
       for(auto j=i+1;j!=a.end();j++)
       {
           val += *j;
           const auto end = begin + q;
           var = max(var,val-(*min_element(next(a.begin(),p),(next(a.begin(),q)))));
           q++;
       }
       p++;
   }
   cout<<var<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You ought to be able to construct test cases and debug a program as simple as this.

Comment: What an absolutely horrible problem description at codechef. Note: if you give your variables meaningful names, it's a lot easier to figure out how you're trying to accomplish it. Either way please provide sample input, output, and desired output.